# Why am I unable to join this thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a multithreading class. The class has a `parallel_process()` function that is overridden with the parallel task. The data to be processed is put in the `queue`. The `worker()` function in each thread keeps calling `parallel_process()` until the `queue` is empty. Results are put in the `results` Queue object. The class definition is:

```
import threading
try:
    from Queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue


class Parallel:

    def __init__(self, pkgs, common=None, nthreads=1):
        self.nthreads = nthreads
        self.threads = []
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.results = Queue()
        self.common = common
        for pkg in pkgs:
            self.queue.put(pkg)

    def parallel_process(self, pkg, common):
        pass

    def worker(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            pkg = self.queue.get()
            self.results.put(self.parallel_process(pkg, self.common))
            self.queue.task_done()
        return

    def start(self):
        for i in range(self.nthreads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = False
            t.start()
            self.threads.append(t)

    def wait_for_threads(self):
        print('Waiting on queue to empty...')
        self.queue.join()
        print('Queue processed. Joining threads...')
        for t in self.threads:
            t.join()
            print('...Thread joined.')

    def get_results(self):
        results = []
        print('Obtaining results...')
        while not self.results.empty():
            results.append(self.results.get())
        return results
```

I use it to create a parallel task:

```
    class myParallel(Parallel):    # return square of numbers in a list
            def parallel_process(self, pkg, common):
                return pkg**2

    p = myParallel(range(50),nthreads=4)
    p.start()
    p.wait_for_threads()
    r = p.get_results()
    print('FINISHED')
```

However all threads do not join every time the code is run. Sometimes only 2 join, sometimes no thread joins. I do not think I am blocking the threads from finishing. What reason could there be for `join()` to not work here?

Comment: What is the output? What do you mean by *only 2 threads join, sometimes no thread joins*?  Does it hang?  Does it not empty the queue?

Comment: `while not self.queue.empty()` - no, no, no! You never use `queue.empty()` for anything other than debugging purposes. It's fundamentally thread-unsafe.

Comment: According to the code, `...Thread joined.` is printed when each thread's `worker()` function returns. Since I am spawning 4 threads, I'd expect 4 print outs. This does not happen. The output screen hangs i.e. the program does not reach the `print('FINISHED')` statement at the end.

Comment: @user2357112 I thought Queue was meant to be used with multithreading. What should I use instead to check if I have anything left in the queue?

Comment: My preferred technique is to put a bunch of shutdown messages in the queue after enqueueing all jobs, and have the workers recognize shutdown messages and shut down when they receive one from the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement may lead to errors:

```
while not self.queue.empty():
    pkg = self.queue.get()
```

With multiple threads pulling items from the queue, there's no guarantee that `self.queue.get()` will return a valid item, even if you check if the queue is empty beforehand. Here is a possible scenario

1. Thread 1 checks the queue and the queue is not empty, control proceeds into the `while` loop.
2. Control passes to Thread 2, which also checks the queue, finds it is not empty and enters the `while` loop.  Thread 2 `gets` an item from the loop.  The queue is now empty.
3. Control passes back to Thread 1, it `gets` an item from the queue, but the queue is now empty, an `Empty` Exception should be raised.

You should just use a `try/except` to get an item from the queue

```
try:
    pkg = self.queue.get_nowait()
except Empty:
    pass
```

Comment: `pass` is unlikely to be the right way to respond to the queue being empty. Also, it's worth mentioning that using `get_nowait` and catching `Empty` doesn't work for cases where producers are expected to be populating the queue while workers are dequeueing entries.

Comment: @user2357112  It's just a small example.  In this case, `return` would probably be appropriate.  In the example from the OP, there are no producers, the queue is completely populated at startup.

Comment: Just so other readers understand:  exception `Empty` is `Queue.Empty` if you haven't imported it explicitly (`from Queue import Empty    # python 2` or `from queue import Empty    # python 3`).

Answer (score 2):

@Brendan Abel identified the cause.  I'd like to suggest a different solution:  `queue.join()` is usually a Bad Idea too.  Instead, create a unique value to use as a sentinel:

```
class Parallel:
    _sentinel = object()
```

At the end of `__init__()`, add one sentinel to the queue for each thread:

```
    for i in range(nthreads):
        self.queue.put(self._sentinel)
```

Change the start of `worker()` like so:

```
    while True:
        pkg = self.queue.get()
        if pkg is self._sentinel:
            break
```

By the construction of the queue, it won't be empty until each thread has seen its sentinel value, so there's no need to mess with the unpredictable `queue.size()`.

Also remove the `queue.join()` and `queue.task_done()` cruft.

This will give you reliable code that's easy to modify for fancier scenarios.  For example, if you want to add more work items *while* the threads are running, fine - just write another method to say "I'm done adding work items now", and move the loop adding sentinels into that.

Comment: I see a flaw here. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You added *n* sentinels for *n* threads. But what guarantee is there that a single thread won't consume multiple sentinels, thus leaving another thread hanging?

Comment: When a thread sees a sentinel, it does `break`.  In context, the thread exits soon after the `break` - the `break` takes it out of the loop.  Therefore a thread cannot consume more than one sentinel.

Comment: Oops! Totally overlooked the `break` part. Thanks!